# new video card brings me to terminal

Tags: 12.04

I recently had to replace my video card, and the new one the I had installed takes me straight to terminal when I turn the computer on. I never get to the log in screen and I don't know the commands at all so I don't know how to get it to work. If it is not compatible, wouldn't it not work at all? I really need help here... The Ubuntu version I have is 12.04 and the video card I had installed is a zotac 210 synergy edition 1gb 64bit ddr3.

Comment: Is it a terminal prompt or a pre-boot BIOS/UEFI screen?

Comment: these are the screens in order; the purple screen that says ubuntu and has the red dots under it, then straight to terminal

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your card, from the make, has an NVidia chipset. A quick search brought up [this page](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1833930&page=2&p=11204401#post11204401), which might help.

The gist of the solution is:

1. Add the repository for the NVidia driver tools.

   `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates`
   `sudo apt-get update`
2. Update the system:

   `sudo apt-get upgrade`
3. Install nvidia-current using the drivers tool you added (jockey):

   `jockey-gtk`

The commands shown there will/*should* work if you can get to a terminal, and not like @belacqua asked, are taken to a BIOS or UEFI screen.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.